# Error calling parent constructor inside a child class

Tags: php, class, constructor

I want to call parent constructor in a child class. here is the parent class in System.php file:

```
class System
{
    private $db_host;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_pass;
    private $connection;
    protected $glb;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_host = "localhost";
        $this->db_name = "signage";
        $this->db_user = "root";
        $this->db_pass = "";
        $this->glb =& $GLOBALS;
    }
}
```

And the child class in User.php file:

```
require_once "System.php";

class User extends System
{
    public $user_id;
    public $user_fullname;
    public $user_password;
    public $user_email;
    public $user_token;
    public $user_type;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

which returns this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot call constructor in C:\xampp\htdocs\signage\classes\User.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\signage\login.php(6): User->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\signage\classes\User.php on line 14`

Where is the problem? I have seen [constructors and distructors in php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and everything should be OK there.

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://3v4l.org/kYG2F

Comment: What is this `$this->glb =& $GLOBALS;`?

Comment: @Dharman I want to store some globals. problem still exists after remove that line.

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense. How do you store some globals? Globals are globals, and are always accessible. What reason could you possibly have to store the reference to GLOBALS in a property? I didn't say it was a problem, but just illogical. It looks useless. Check the link I gave, I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ehsan globals in classes tend to never be the right option.